# Why is it that in $\mathbb{F}_q \setminus 0$, there are exactly as many squares as non-squares?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Why is it that in $\mathbb F_q\setminus\{0\}$, when $q\neq 2^k$, there are exactly as many squares as non-squares?

My combinatorics textbook states this without proof :/

Comment: I hope your textbook makes an exception for the case $q=2^k$.

Comment: -checks- yep, they say "odd prime"

Comment: consider the homomorphism $F^*_{q}$ to the multiplicative group $\{+1,-1\}$, where squares are sent to $1$ and non-squares are sent to $-1$. By first homomorphism theorem, $F^{*}_{q}/ker$ is isomorphic to the image, i.e. $\{1,-1\}$, by equating the cardinality of both sets, we have the assertion.

Comment: Please try to make the body of the question self contained, even if the question was in the title, repeating it in the body is not a bad idea.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is true if and only if $q$ is odd. Given that $q$ is odd, $\mathbb{F}_q^\times=\mathbb{F}_q\setminus\{0\}$ is an abelian group of even order (in fact it is cyclic, but we don't need to know that for this argument). Consider the squaring homomorphism $s:\mathbb{F}_q^\times\to \mathbb{F}_q^\times$, defined by $s(a)=a^2$. What is its kernel? What does that mean the size of the image must be?

Comment: Ooooooo clever :D thanks!

Comment: Just a quick comment: when Zev says "in fact it is cyclic, but this is not necessary", he means that it is not necessary to *know* that the group is cyclic -- one gets away by knowing what the subgroup of order $2$ elements looks like (I make arguments like this in my number theory notes to avoid existence of primitive roots until it is absolutely necessary).  One definitely needs the group to **be** cyclic, or at least not an arbitrary finite abelian group of even order: for instance in $\{\pm 1\}^k$ only the identity element is a square.

Comment: @Pete: Thanks for pointing out the ambiguity; I've clarified my answer as well.

Answer (score 4):

Define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb{F}_q^*$ with $a \sim b \Leftrightarrow a^2 = b^2 $ . The number of squares is the number of equivalence classes of this relation. Now $x^2 = y^2$ if and only if $y = \pm x $. Thus there are two elements in every equivalence class, since $x \neq -x$ for every $x \in \mathbb{F}_q^*$. Therefore there are $\frac{1}{2}|\mathbb{F}_q^*|$ equivalence classes.

EDIT: As others have noted, $q$ should be odd. In a field of order $2^k$ every element is a square: the map $x \mapsto x^2$ is then injective and thus bijective, because we're talking about finite fields here.